# How can I avoid db_file_sequential_read on an index during inserts

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with two indexes.  I'm running inserts one at a time, committing every 1000 rows.  I can't do bulk inserts because the business logic requires checking the updated data row by row.

My index is causing very high db_file_sequential_read waits.  I can order the incoming data to avoid these on this index, but then I suffer the same penalty on a different index.

The actual table is too long to disable and subsequently recreate the indexes.

This shows the slowness I am suffering from.  The first set of numbers is from a staging server using an encrypted tablespace.  The second set of numbers is from a production server using a non-encrypted tablespace.

```
-- create random test data in foo
create table foo as (
  select dbms_random.random() id, dbms_random.string('U', 25) val 
  from dual connect by level <= 100000
);
create index foo_id_idx on foo (id, val);

-- create data table in bar
create table bar as (
  select * from foo where 0 = 1
);

-- populate bar with unordered data (3.12s / 1.22s)
insert into bar select * from foo; commit;

-- add id index
create index bar_id_idx on bar (id);

-- populate indexed bar with unordered data (36.73s / 2.24s)
truncate table bar;
insert into bar select * from foo; commit;

-- populate indexed bar with id ordered data (4.84s / 0.6s)
truncate table bar;
insert into bar select * from foo order by id; commit;

-- add val index (actual production setup)
create index bar_val_idx on bar (val);

-- populate multi-indexed bar with unordered data (84.482s / 3.1s)
truncate table bar;
insert into bar select * from foo order by val; commit;

-- populate multi-indexed bar with id ordered data (50.641s / 2.631s)
truncate table bar;
insert into bar select * from foo order by id; commit;

-- alter index on foo to support order by clause
drop index foo_id_idx;
create index foo_val_idx on foo (val, id);

-- populate multi-indexed bar with val ordered data (37.31s / 2.66s)
truncate table bar;
insert into bar select * from foo order by val; commit;
```

This seems like such a huge penalty for the second index to go from 5s to 84s.  Of course I can bypass most of the penalty for one index by ordering the data, but not for both.  Should I be looking at buffer, cache, memory or something else to help avoid the disk IO, or should I be looking at some other strategy like index organized tables?

EDIT 1: Added numbers from a production box & wait information.

In one hour on production with the actual insert process (not the simplified example above):
Executions  56,715
Rows Processed  56,715
Parses  1
Disk Reads  36,958
Sorts   0
Buffer Gets     754,970
db_file_sequential_read wait 323s
memory/cpu wait 26s

Comment: What are the specs of the machine you are running on? These timings seem very slow. A few other things. i. What is the processing that needs to be done for each row? Are you *sure* this cannot be done as part of a bull insert?  ii. Are you sure the wait events are coming from index maintenance?  iii. What is the size of your table, both in terms of rows and GB

Comment: @Aaron, I agree with BobC that your run times seem ridiculously slow.  I ran the entire script on my desktop PC and all of your times are over 10 times slower than mine.  Before you worry about the data structures you might want to look into the OS, hardware, SAN, etc.  Or take a look at some AWR data to see how the database is performing, such as: `select *
from dba_hist_sysmetric_history
where metric_name = 'Average Synchronous Single-Block Read Latency';`.

Comment: @BobC This is a staging server with specs much lower than the production server, but otherwise configured identically, and using the same NAS.  I also realized I was using an encrypted tablespace for the tables and indexes.  That to say - I am more concerned with the relative differences in performance in the example.  I added the numbers from the production server in an unencrypted tablespace to the original question.  If you still think the performance is poor then I would be curious to investigate further.

Comment: @BobC i Part of the per row process is querying the full dataset, including any just-inserted row.  We could make adjustments, such as load tables, but are really interested if we have stumbled upon some other underlying problem here. ii If the index does not exist or the data is inserted in order the waits disappear, therefore I concluded it was index maintenance.

Comment: @BobC iii The production table is 4 fields, ~500m rows and ~18 GB, range partitioned monthly (84x) by a date field, in an encrypted tablespace.  The ID index is non-partitioned in an unencrypted tablespace.  The val index is range partitioned (12x) based on the first two char of val, in an unencrypted tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the same data stored in two different orders, if you store two copies:

- materialized view
- backed by IOT with (val, id) key
- refresh on commit
- advanced query rewrite enabled, for mview index to be usable by queries against the original table

This may be updated in bulk, thus giving some profit to pay off its own maintenance. Keep your fingers crossed for advanced query rewrite to work properly.

Comment: So you are suggesting two set of inserts? And how does an IOT help?

Comment: No way :) materialized view is maintained automatically.

Yes, you need MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG on the table for that, too

Comment: you don't have to keep both indexes on the same table. As mview is IOT based, it automatically maintains the storage order. Combined with supposedly bulk automatic refresh on commit, this may help.

Comment: Keep (id, val) on the table, and (val, id) index on mview IOT

Comment: So you have proposed an idea with no numerical facts to back it. I fail to how this would help. I would suggest presenting some comparable numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Executable example for the mview.
If, and only if, the row-by-row insertion of second index is a problem, then this has slim chance of performing faster, due to bulk update of the mview on commit.

```
set timing on

create table foo (
    id number,
    val varchar2(30)
) pctfree 0;

create index foo_id_idx on foo (id, val);

alter table foo
    add constraint pk_foo primary key (id) using index foo_id_idx;

create materialized view log on foo with primary key;

create table mv_foo (
    id number,
    val varchar2(30),
    constraint pk_mv_foo primary key (val, id)
) organization index;

create materialized view mv_foo
on prebuilt table
refresh fast on commit with primary key
enable query rewrite
as
select id, val
from foo;

begin
  -- to reset mview staleness
  dbms_mview.refresh('mv_foo', method => 'c');
end;
/

insert into foo(id, val)
select dbms_random.random(), dbms_random.string('U', 25)
  from dual connect by level <= 10000;
commit;

begin
  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'foo');
  dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'mv_foo');
end;
/

explain plan for
select /*+ first rows */
  id, val
from foo
order by id, val;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

explain plan for
select /*+ first rows */
  id, val
from foo
order by val, id;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

Please see how mview IOT is transparently used when FOO filtered by VAL in the second statement:

```
explain plan for select * from foo where id = :x

explain plan succeeded.
6ms elapsed
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2466643623

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |            |     1 |    33 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| FOO_ID_IDX |     1 |    33 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("ID"=TO_NUMBER(:Z))


explain plan for select * from foo where val = :x

explain plan succeeded.
25ms elapsed
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display)

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 386525678

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |           |     1 |    33 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  INDEX RANGE SCAN| PK_MV_FOO |     1 |    33 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("MV_FOO"."VAL"=:X)
```

You need QUERY REWRITE system privilege for that to work.